# Wordpress not printing title if there is no loop

Tags: wordpress, title

Im using wordpress 3.0 here:

http://www.adventure-service.com

On homepage i am using template that creates that content without wordpress loop.

But on contact page i am using the loop:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
            <div id='content'>
                <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
            </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Ofc on contact page title works just fine.

Any idea what to do? What code to show you? In header.php i have this for title:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '| adventure-service.com', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the loop, [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_title) is always null on the site front page. That is why the Wordpress codex encourages you to include the blog name in your title. In your case you probably want do something like this (after setting your blog's name to 'adventure-service.com'):

```
<title><?php wp_title(' | ', true, 'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Comment: Yap, that did the trick. :) Didnt know that about 'null on site front page'. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_title() without seperator parameter anywhere like this:

```
<?php wp_title( '' ); ?>
```